# How to mark a base package as not user installed while avoiding dnf autoremove?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dependencies, dnf

On a freshly installed Fedora system, base packages such as `sudo` are not counted as user installed, i.e. `dnf repoquery --userinstalled | grep sudo` comes back empty. At the same time, these packages are also not considered by `dnf autoremove`, i.e. the command does not try to remove them. So far, so good.

Now, if I mark `sudo` as removable using `dnf mark remove sudo`, a subsequent `dnf autoremove` attempts (and fails) to remove it. The only way I know to again prevent autoremove to target `sudo` is to mark it as explicity user installed using `dnf mark install sudo`. However, now `sudo` has a different state than it had in the beginning: `dnf repoquery --userinstalled | grep sudo` now shows the `sudo` package.

My question is: How do I reset the state of a base package such as `sudo`? That is, how can I achieve that `dnf repoquery --userinstalled | grep sudo` comes back empty while `dnf autoremove` does not attempt to remove the package?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that yet. Your best bet is to not cause the situation in the first place.

Comment: I see. What exactly is keeping base packages like sudo from being affected by autoremove in the first place? Is it some custom logic of dnf I could have a look at? If so, where?

Comment: sudo is not an important enough package for such protection, but actual critical packages like dnf itself or systemd are protected. Try removing one of those and watch it refuse to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found how it is supposed to work:

Packages can not only be marked as 'install' or 'remove' but also as 'group'. This seems to be the default state for packages that were installed using `dnf group install`. In the example above `dnf mark group sudo` restores the original state of the `sudo` package.